# Passing Parameters from View to Action in MVC

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently trying to take a value from a drop down list, store it into a variable, and pass it into a controller's action result. When I run my code, the Index is supposed to store the value of the selected item in the dropdown box in the variable `SelectedDistrict`, then then go to the Query action. Query will take a variable of `DistrictViewModel` as a parameter and then use `var school = getQuery(variable.SelectedDistrict)` to go into the function I have. In the function however, it's saying that the variable `sd` is null whenever i debug. Maybe the value from the drop down box is not storing properly? In the end, I want to display in a table all of the schools in my school table that come from the selected district in the drop down. The table is not being populated because of the null value. Here is my code for more clarity.

- District View Model:

[image: District View Model]

- School View Model:

[image]

- Controller w/ getQuery function:

[image]

- Index View:

[image]

- Query View:

[image]

- The table when I run my code:
- [image]

Comment: When you are on the Query page, what is the URL? I assume that there is no query string there.

Comment: @howcheng `http://uwfii-util-mcs-schools.azurewebsites.net/District/Query` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: The problem is that your controller method for Query is expecting some data to be passed in the form of an object, but you aren't passing anything to it. If it's a GET request (and it appears to be because you just set `location.href` on click), the values would need to be in the query string. Alternatively you can make your form POST to that controller action instead.

Comment: So place [HttpPost] above my query action result? I wanted to submit the value chosen from the select list and save it into the variable `SelectedDistrict`. But what you're saying is that the value can be posted directly to the Query action result as soon as a value is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your controller method for Query is expecting some data to be passed in the form of an object, but you aren't passing anything to it. If it's a GET request (and it appears to be because you just set `location.href` on click), the values would need to be in the query string. Alternatively you can make your form POST to that controller action instead.

You'll need `<form>` tags. You can GET or POST to your controller method, it won't matter (model binding works either way). It depends on whether you want people to be able to deep-link directly to the search results or not.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Query", "District") method="get">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDistrict, Model.Districts)
  <button type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

That pretty much should do it, or at least get you on the right path.

Comment: That did it! I realized that the value from the dropdownlist was not being passed but I can't believe i didn't realize that a simple form would do the trick. I thought that after the selection was made, I could call the variable from the modelview and pass it into the Query method but that wasn't the case. Thank you!